# Searching Text in Memory without Visual Component in C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am using C++Builder 10.3 with the VCL 32bit platform. I need to know the best way to search a text file in memory. I wrote the code below which opens a text file into the RichEdit component and searches for and selects some text. The RichEdit is intended to be used as a Visual Component. The TMemoryStream and TStringStream are used in memory but do not offer the methods FindText, SelStart, SelLength and SelText. Can you show how to do this in memory?

```
UnicodeString MyCrumb;
int StartPos=0, ToEnd=0, FoundAt=0, StartCrumb=0;
TSearchTypes mySearchTypes = TSearchTypes();


RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromFile( "CrumbFile.txt" );

ToEnd = RichEdit1->Text.Length();

FoundAt  = RichEdit1->FindText(L"CrumbStore", StartPos, ToEnd, mySearchTypes);
StartPos = FoundAt+10;
FoundAt  = RichEdit1->FindText("crumb", StartPos, ToEnd, mySearchTypes);
StartPos = FoundAt+8;

StartCrumb = FoundAt+8;
FoundAt  = RichEdit1->FindText("}", StartPos, ToEnd, mySearchTypes);
EndPos = FoundAt-1;

RichEdit1->SelStart  = StartPos;
RichEdit1->SelLength = ( EndPos-StartPos );
MyCrumb = RichEdit1->SelText;
```

Comment: Have you tried `System.StrUtils.PosEx` yet?

Comment: @TomBrunberg `Pos/Ex()` requires a `String` as input, which means loading the file AND decoding its content to UTF-16 in memory (assuming you even know the file's encoding up front) before you can then search it. You can use `TFile.ReadAllText()` for that, for instance. But this is not very efficient for large files. `TStreamReader` might make more sense, since it can read a text file line-by-line (via its `ReadLine()` method), and then you can search the individual lines with `Pos/Ex()` as needed.  Of course, this won't work well for text spanning line boundaries. A RichEdit can handle that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right, I did not really consider the actual reading. My comment was more directed to the act of searching as that appeared to be the main concern for OP.

Comment: @homebase what does the `CrumbFile.txt` file actually look like? This code implies the file data has a structure to it, so there may be a smarter/better way to parse it then just using brute force searches. When I search for `CrumbStore` online, I see examples of JSON, for instance for financial quotes from Yahoo, that would match your code. Is that true? If so, why are you not using a JSON parser, like the [one provided by Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON)?

Comment: The file is a webpage which is saved as a .txt file. The file can be loaded into any component that has a LoadFromFile() method.

Comment: Is it possible to use TRichEdit with a smart pointer like this:  std::auto_ptr<TRichEdit> MyRichEdit(new TRichEdit ); When I tried this I get the message E2285 Could not find a match for 'TRichEdit::TRichEdit()' Do I need to add a "#pragma link" or a "#include" to make this work?

Comment: If you use RegEx you could get the value you want from the HTML with about 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VCL way is to use `TStringList` class instead of visual components. However, entire file will be loaded in the memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
void FindTextVcl() 
{
    unique_ptr<TStringList> txt(new TStringList());
    txt->LoadFromFile(L"Example.txt"); // Use appropriate TEncoding if need
    for (int line_num = 0; line_num != txt->Count; line_num++)
    {
        int pos = txt->Strings[line_num].Pos("there");
        if (pos > 0)
        {
            cout << "Found at line " << line_num + 1 << ", position " << pos << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The standard library way is like the following example (use `wstring` and `wifstream` for UTF-16). 
This works for big files because only current string is loaded in the memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void FindTextStd()
{
    ifstream txt("Example.txt");
    if (txt.is_open())
    {
        size_t pos = 0;
        size_t line_num = 0;
        string line;
        while (getline(txt, line))
        {
            line_num++;
            pos = line.find("there");
            if (pos != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "Found at line " << line_num << ", position " << pos + 1 << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```